# How to deploy a jBPM (jBPM3) project which generates processdefinition.xml file programmatically?

Tags: java, deployment, jbpm

Deploying the jBPM project seems easy using Eclipse when I use designer tool to generate the processdefinition.xml file.
But, I wanted to generate the processdefinition.xml using java. When I tried so, it works fine, but not able to deploy it directly.

As there is no deployment option is shown in eclipse. 
How to deploy it now ?

Comment: Dynamically generating the processdefinition.xml and then changing it accordingly, using java. This is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method for 3.2.x in you code..

```
deployProcessDefinition(ProcessDefinition processDefinition)
{
  getGraphSession().deployProcessDefinition(processDefinition);
}
```